# Tokyo Dialect, 東京弁 : 形容詞 vs 形容動詞

Tags: slang, adjectives, dialects, contractions

In Tokyo Dialect, they transform some i-adjectives so that they become

sugoi - suggee/sugee

yabai - yabee

itai - ittee

/

is there any in na-adjectives? Like

shizukana shizukka

genkina - genkki

Comment: I'm confused why you're hypothesizing gemination of the final occurring constant.  Are you suggesting that しずかなところ would be rendered しずっかところ?  That would surely be interesting.  Have you heard this sort thing in spoken speech?  There are cases where の, as the possessive marker, is spoken as ん and others where a final る is spoken as ん.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no, AFAIK.

However, if I may go beyond your restriction of "na-adjectives", things get interesting.

For example, daikon だいこん is pronounced as deekon でーこん. Daikon is not an adjective, but you see a similar pattern as sugoi / sugee.

BTW, this is not limited to Tokyo-ben. We say Okayama-ben turns "daikon taitoite" だいこんたいといて （i.e. 大根を炊いておいて） into "deekon teeteete" でーこんてーてーて. In fact, Okayama おかやま itself can be pronounced as Okyaama おきゃーま.

So when you mention "In Tokyo Dialect, they transform some i-adjectives so that they become...", well, it's not just Tokyo Dialect, and it's not just adjectives.